# Terminal behaving strangely after resizing (no new line)

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome

On Arch Linux with Gnome 3.18, I have the problem of terminals behaving
strangely when I resize a terminal window and enter some commands, such as `ls`
or `mpv`, for example, and resize again by dragging the window border with the
mouse cursor.

When I press <kbd>↑</kbd> to go back in history, and the line is long , no new
line (or line break) is created, but the same line overwritten from left to
right. When I hold <kbd>↑</kbd> on the keyboard, the prompt moves to top and
'eats' the terminal output above. I have tried an could see similar behaviour in
gnome-terminal, lxterminal and xterm, all started from a gnome session.

Here's a screencast demonstrating this strange behaviour: https://vimeo.com/147162618

What could this be and where could I search the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is due to a quirk in the way `bash` handles window-resizing events: it *can* capture `SIGWINCH` so that it knows how to update its notion of the screen width for editing command-lines.

The place to look is at the `checkwinsize` option:

> **`checkwinsize`**
>
> If set, Bash checks the window size after each command and, if necessary, updates the values of **`LINES`** and **`COLUMNS`**.

The whole feature has had problems:

- [Re: Troublesome checkwinsize (none) behaviour](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-07/msg00063.html)
- [checkwinsize only works in interactive shells](http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/checkwinsize-only-works-in-interactive-shells-td11281.html)

but generally the advice given is to set the option if it is not already set:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Further reading:

- [How to solve the issue that a Terminal screen is messed up? (usually after a resizing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61608/105132)
- [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) (Bash Reference Manual)